# I'm getting an invallid syntax error with my class

Tags: python, class

I've been learning python for a while now but I really want to start using oop but I'm having trouble understanding it, please can you tell me where I'm going wrong with my class.

```
class Savecookies():

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def __init__(self, site, url):
        self.site = site
        self.url = url

    def twitter(driver, self.site, self.url):

if __name__=='__main__':
    cooks = Savecookies('twitter', 'https://twitter.com/')
```

My error:

```
  File "twitter_test2.py", line 26
    def twitter(driver, self.site, self.url):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I hope the indentation you posted here isn't the indentation you're trying to run...

Comment: The twitter function has no body. Put a `pass` in it if it's supposed to be empty.

Comment: @Arc676 What do you mean I indented 4 spaces on each line. the twitter method isn't blank in the script I just posted it lie that because that's where I'm getting the error.

Comment: Oh, and you can't put a dot in the argument names.

Comment: @Elektito It's not empty in the script, I just posted it like that because the error points to the arguments in the parameters.

Comment: Don’t post broken code and ask us what is broken about your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
def twitter(driver, self.site, self.url):
```

What’s that?

First of all, methods need *a body*. Otherwise they are incomplete. The simplest body would be to just do `pass` (i.e. do nothing). But you probably want to add actual stuff in there.

Second, your arguments make no sense at all. The first argument of a method is `self`, and then you specify which other arguments you want the method to accept. And argument names need to be valid variables, so you cannot have a dot in there. And if you want the method to access `self.site` and `self.url`, you can just do that without needing to pass it to the function (since you have access to `self`). In your case, you already have the site and url from the `Savecookies` object, so you probably want something like this:

```
def twitter(self, driver):
    # Do something useful here
    print(self.site, self.url)
    print(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

in case `twitter` is an instance method 
change

```
def twitter(driver, self.site, self.url):
```

to

```
def twitter(self):
    #now do something with the params
    print(self.driver, self.site, self.url)
```

Basically, let it access the `site` and `url` instance attributes set by `__init__`

and let it access the `driver` class attribute set in the class

Both types of attributes can be reached through `self.`, there is no need to pass it again as a parameter.